# Fragement getArguments() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass data from my activity to a fragment but I get a null pointer on Bundle.getString()

I've also noticed, that it goes to the fragment even without the fragment transaction code

Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends BrowseFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String myValue = bundle.getString("message");
    }
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String myMessage = "Stackoverflow is cool!";
        bundle.putString("message", myMessage );
        MainFragment fragInfo = new MainFragment();
        fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_browse_fragment, fragInfo);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_browse_fragment"
    android:name="my.package.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="tv"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: use `getArguments().getX(KEY);` instead `Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();` because `getArguments();`  take a look here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()

Comment: Please provide the actual stack trace

Comment: @MohamedRa did not work. getArguments() is coming back null

Comment: your fragment is already in the xml, so when you create it again, it is a new one. Don't put the fragment in the xml if you want to pass arguments to it.

Comment: @njzk2 if I don't put it in the xml, what id do I pass to replace() `transaction.replace(R.id.main_browse_fragment, fragInfo);`

Comment: Have `FrameLayout` with ID in your XML and replace that.

Comment: @code511788465541441 like Eugen said. a container (typically a framelayout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the fragment in your xml layout to simple FrameLayout. Creation of fragment from xml cause the exception, because it hasn't arguments (They are added manually in your Activity code)